# My elif Statment is having a syntax error

Tags: python-3.x

Hi Everyone when I try to run my program it pops up a box and says invalid syntax then makes the elif turn red

```
sales_amount = int(input('what is your sales amount to your commission rate 
Example: 5000$ to 2%'))
goal_salary = int(input('what is your goal salary'))
commission_rate = float(input('what is your commissioin rate to your sales 
amount Example: 5000$ to 2%  P.S. please write as decimal'))

final_sales_amount=sales_amount
final_commission_rate=commission_rate
the_number=1
commission=0
sales=0.01

while sales_amount*commission_rate==goal_salary:
    print('your sales amount is', sales)
    print('your commission rate is', commission) 
    break
elif the_number*sales_amount==0.01:
    the_number+1
    commission+commission_rate
else:
    sales=sales+0.01
```

Comment: You cannot put an `elif` after a `while`. You can only put it after an `if`.

Answer (score 0):

A `elif` is used if first `if` are not matching cond.
example:

```py
a = 1
if a ==2:
 print('lol')
elif a == 1:
 print('wow')
```

in this example, the output is `wow` but if cond in `if` is True, the elif will not be detected(or as not going that `elif` code).

`Else` is used if no cond in any `if` and `elif` is True.
for example:

```py
a = 3
if a == 1 or a ==5:
 print('1/5')
elif a == 2 or a == 4:
 print('2/4')
else:
 print('i have nothing')
```

and the output will be `i have nothing` because `a == 1 or a ==5` is not true, also `a ==2 or a == 4` is not true too, so else,`else: print('i have nothing')` is the code's way to solve the solution